# Is there a way to stub method using sinon where method has two arguments

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Let me explain the problem statement:

I am using Mocha, Chai and Sinon. I am trying to stub a method which looks something like below:

```js
myNamespace.myMethod({
  beforeSend() { ... }
}, callback)
```

I want to stub `myMethod` and call `beforeSend` as well as `callback`. I am not able to find a solution that works. I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```js
sinon.stub(myNamespace, 'myMethod').yieldsTo('beforeSend', {}).callsArg(1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to chain two different behaviors *for the same function call* like this so `.callsArg(1)` ends up overwriting `.yieldsTo('beforeSend', {})`

For something like this you will need to provide a fake implementation with [`callsFake`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.7/stubs/#stubcallsfakefakefunction):

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');

const myNamespace = {
  myMethod: (obj, callback) => { }
}

it('myMethod', () => {
  const beforeSendArg = { };

  sinon.stub(myNamespace, 'myMethod').callsFake((obj, callback) => {
    obj.beforeSend(beforeSendArg);
    callback();
  });

  const beforeSend = sinon.spy();
  const callback = sinon.spy();

  myNamespace.myMethod({ beforeSend }, callback);

  sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(beforeSend, beforeSendArg);  // Success!
  sinon.assert.called(callback);  // Success!
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try!